# Does Dart have something like File.separator in Java?

Tags: file, dart, separator

Does Dart have some function or property that can tell whether the OS uses "/" or "\" in the file system paths, like File.separator in Java?

Answer (score 12):

```
import 'dart:io';

Platform.pathSeparator
```

Small correction from previous answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
import 'dart:io';
...
Platform.Platform.pathSeparator
```

See also [Dart by example - Dart I/O and Command Line Apps - Getting the path separator for the current platform](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-by-example/#getting-the-path-separator-for-the-current-platform)